# When is a finitely presented positively admissible group uniformly reachable?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

This is a follow-up from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359035/presentation-of-groups-and-positive-expressions).

For a finitely presented group $G=⟨S|R⟩$, a *positive element* g∈G  is an element of G that can be written as a finite product of elements of $S$ only.
A *positive expression* of $g\in G$ is a word $w$ with elements of $S$ its alphabet and only contain elements of $S$ and $w$ reduce to $g$ after applying relations in $R$. A relation $R$ is a *positive relation* if it can be rewritten as $w_1=w_2$ with $w_1$, $w_2$ positive elements. A *basic positive replacement* of $G$ is to replace $w_1$ with $w_2$ or $w_2$ with $w_1$ for some positive relation $w_1=w_2$. A group presentation $<S|R>$ is *positively admissible* if all its relations are positive relations and no element of $S$ is the inverse of any element of $S$ (This can be simplified to $S\cap S^{-1}=\varnothing$). A group $G$ is *positively admissible* if there exists some positively admissible presentation $G=<S|R>$. For a positively admissible presentation $<S|R>$ such that any positive expression w for some positive element g can be deformed into another positive expression w′ of g only by finite applications of basic positive replacements, we call g a *reachable element with respect to $<S|R>$*. If there exists a positively admissible presentation such that $g$ is a reachable element with respect to $<S|R>$, we call g a *reachable element*. A finitely presented positively admissible group with all elements reachable with respect to a particular $<S|R>$ (which is independent of what the element is) is called a *uniformly reachable group*.

What kind of conditions can we add so that a finitely presented positively admissible group is uniformly reachable? To be more specific, are braid groups reachable?

Edited: Some definitions have been changed since reachability is dependent on the presentation.

Comment: Since there are finite groups that are not reachable, none of the conditions you mention are sufficient. But yes, braid groups, and more generally Garside groups, are reachable, because the Garside monoid embeds into the corresponding Garside group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Would you please give me more details? I would like to read about some new research in this area and the relations between groups and monoids that have the same presentation in general. I currently deal with the picture groups by Professor Kiyoshi Igusa which are very close to braid groups..